# Change theme dynamically for multiple view - Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-theme

I am trying change theme when the app device is offline. But to achieve changing the background color is not gonna help and i needed to change the whole view and the text colors. But for that getting all the view with FindViewById is not an effective method to achieve that as I got lots of views to the Activity and as i tried using Themes

`<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>`

But as it shows only one colored TextView I cant use this method to activity as it has multiple colors and changing theme has to be done before you create the activity.

Please provide a solution which supports changing theme with multiple colored View

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Utils {
    private static int sTheme;

    public final static int THEME_MATERIAL_LIGHT = 0;
    public final static int THEME_YOUR_CUSTOM_THEME = 1;

    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme) {
        sTheme = theme;
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
        activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }

    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {
        switch (sTheme) {
        default:
        case THEME_MATERIAL_LIGHT:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_Material_Light);
            break;
        case THEME_YOUR_CUSTOM_THEME:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.Theme_YOUR_CUSTOM_THEME);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**In Your Activity:**

```
 @Override // Any Activity
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // MUST BE SET BEFORE setContentView
            Utils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
            // AFTER SETTING THEME
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_theme);
        }
```